# IP routing table lookup in .net

Tags: c#, .net, routes, ip

I have a multi-homed machine and need to answer this question:

Given an IP address of the remote machine, which local interface is appropriate to use for communication.

This needs to be done in C#. I can do this query using Win32 Socket and SIO_ROUTING_INTERFACE_QUERY but looking around in the .net framework documentation I haven't found an equivalent for it.

Comment: I haven't managed to get a socket working to provide the routing table, but this may get you started (if you need a point in the right direction) - http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know about this, so just had a look in the Visual Studio Object browser, and it looks like you can do this from the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace.

In that namespace is a `Socket` class which contains a method `IOControl`. One of the overloads for this method takes an `IOControlCode` (enum in the same namespace) which contains an entry for `RoutingInterfaceQuery'.

I'll try and put some code together as an example now.

Comment: Thanks - that should do it.

Comment: That example would be of great help ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Someone was nice enough to writez the code, see https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/7464800/

```
private static IPEndPoint QueryRoutingInterface(
          Socket socket,
          IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint)
{
    SocketAddress address = remoteEndPoint.Serialize();

    byte[] remoteAddrBytes = new byte[address.Size];
    for (int i = 0; i < address.Size; i++) {
        remoteAddrBytes[i] = address[i];
    }

    byte[] outBytes = new byte[remoteAddrBytes.Length];
    socket.IOControl(
                IOControlCode.RoutingInterfaceQuery, 
                remoteAddrBytes, 
                outBytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < address.Size; i++) {
        address[i] = outBytes[i];
    }

    EndPoint ep = remoteEndPoint.Create(address);
    return (IPEndPoint)ep;
}
```

which is used like (example!):

```
IPAddress remoteIp = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.55");
IpEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteIp, 0);
Socket socket = new Socket(
                      AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                      SocketType.Dgram, 
                      ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = QueryRoutingInterface(socket, remoteEndPoint );
Console.WriteLine("Local EndPoint is: {0}", localEndPoint);
```

Please note that although one is specifying an `IpEndPoint` with a Port, the port is irrelevant. Also, the returned `IpEndPoint.Port` is always `0`.