# How to do determine which IP address, of two available, email messages are sent from the server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

On my server machine (S.O. Windows server 2008) there are two different ip addresses because there are two network sockets.

This server sends email messages periodically using `C# ASPNET` and `System.Net.Mail`.

How to do determine with which IP address, of two available, these email messages are sent from the server?

I have tried using this code but the IP address getted is only the first of the two, also if command `ping myserver` the output is the second ip value.

Any suggestion?

```
string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
Response.Write(myIP.ToString());
```

**update #01**

```
private static IPEndPoint QueryRoutingInterface(
          Socket socket,
          IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint)
{
    SocketAddress address = remoteEndPoint.Serialize();

    byte[] remoteAddrBytes = new byte[address.Size];
    for (int i = 0; i < address.Size; i++)
    {
        remoteAddrBytes[i] = address[i];
    }

    byte[] outBytes = new byte[remoteAddrBytes.Length];
    socket.IOControl(
                IOControlCode.RoutingInterfaceQuery,
                remoteAddrBytes,
                outBytes);
    for (int i = 0; i < address.Size; i++)
    {
        address[i] = outBytes[i];
    }

    EndPoint ep = remoteEndPoint.Create(address);
    return (IPEndPoint)ep;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        IPAddress remoteIp = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.55");
        IpEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteIp, 0);
        Socket socket = new Socket(
                              AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                              SocketType.Dgram,
                              ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = QueryRoutingInterface(socket, remoteEndPoint);
        Console.WriteLine("Local EndPoint is: {0}", localEndPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need your local routing lookup table and the IP Address of your destination: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625023/ip-routing-table-lookup-in-net Look at `route print` in the console to see the configuration of the routing table.

Comment: @Michael thanks for help. I have tried but I have error on this line of my code `IpEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteIp, 0);` Please see **update #01** on my first question.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the referenced answer, `IPEndPoint` (uppercase P) or `var` will work.